# Read a text file using command line arguments doesn't work

Tags: c, pointers, text, makefile, ncurses

So I’ve got a directory called temp

```
temp
```

It contains:

```
assets bin src include Makefile
```

The assets directory contains a "file.txt" file, which is filled with some keyboard alphabetic characters.

My src folder also includes the file "file.c" which is

```
#include "file.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    initscr();
    noecho();
    cbreak();

    char ch;
    FILE * ptr;

    if(strcmp(argv[1],"file.txt") == 0)
    {
        ptr = fopen("file.txt","r");

        if(ptr == NULL)
        {
            mvprintw(0,0,"Error reading the file\n");
            refresh();
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            while( ( ch =fgetc(ptr) ) != EOF)
                mvprintw(0,0,"%c",ch);
                refresh();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        mvprintw(0,0,"you didn't specify the right .txt file");
        exit(1);
    }
    endwin();

    fclose(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

The makefile contains:

```
all:
        gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -Iinclude src/file.c -o bin/runMe -lncurses
```

However after successful compilation, going to the bin directory and typing `./runMe file.txt` ends up printing nothing new on the screen (doesn't print the characters "abc" which are in the text file (located in the assets directory).

What's going wrong?

Comment: Given your example, it should print "you didn't specify the right .txt file" (because the code wants "input.txt") Do you need to put a refresh after the print?  Will calling exit() immediately after it remove any output?  Also, you should only call `fclose(ptr);` when you successfully open your file and are done with it.

Comment: This code looks odd. It looks like you must pass it a file called "input.txt" from the current director you're executing from, or it will fail. When it fails, it prints the error message with ncurses, but exists and probably clears the window with `endwin`.

Comment: 'Tis curious that you check that the user specifies `file.txt` but you open `input.txt`.  That fails — there isn't an `input.txt` in the `bin` directory.  Even if you clean it up to open `argv[1]` instead of a fixed name, you have to specify `../assets/file.txt` if you run the program in the `bin` directory.

Comment: It was a typo on my part, I was thinking of another file from another program I was working on before, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your executable from within the bin directory, then you are trying to open your file in the bin directory, where it isn't.

Run the file from temp, as ./bin/runMe file.txt where the fopen line reads "assets/file.txt"

You have to be explicit where you run a program and where a file is.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading one character at a time and printing these characters at the same location (0, 0). I assume you should see the last character containd in your file at location 0, 0 of your window. Why not using printf?

[EDIT]
As you print characters, increment the x location.

```
int x= 0;
while( ( ch =fgetc(ptr) ) != EOF) {
            mvprintw(x,0,"%c",ch);
            x++;
}
```

Comment: Because I'm required to use the ncurses library.